# Convert String ["Scenario 1", "Scenario 2"] to Array

Tags: java, arrays, text

I have the following **code:**

```
String text = "[\"Scenario 1\", \"Scenario 2\"]"
```

I need to convert `"text"` to `Array`. I know that I can replace [ ] " and I do a `split(",")` but is there a way easy?

Comment: That code won't compile.

Comment: this string doesn't look right... Too many `"`.

Comment: I changed the code

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen That code won't compile, I think in a method for example toArray or similar

Comment: I tested but nor works

Comment: I'm sorry, I obviously need some more coffee. This will do it: `String[] parts = text.replaceAll("[\\[\\]']", "").split(",");`

Comment: I think that you need more coffee :), remember I use " instance of '

Comment: Don't see what `instanceof` has to do with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the `text` is well formatted you can use `String.substring()` instead of regex.

```
String text = "['Stack1', 'Stack2']";
StringTokenizer tkn = new StringTokenizer(text.substring(1, text.length() - 1), ", ");
while (tkn.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String v = tkn.nextToken();
    System.out.println(v.substring(1, v.length() - 1)); // Stack1 Stack2
}
```

Comment: I got in system => Stack

Comment: You did something wrong, see [ideone example](https://ideone.com/wVuIe9)

Comment: I use " instanceof ', maybe the issue?

Answer (score 2):

It seems, you mean `"[\"String 1\", \"String 2\"]"`
Ofcourse you can use jackson ObjectMapper to read it like a json string and deserialize to array. But it doesn't looks like easier way.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest version I can come up with is this:

```
String text = "['Stack1', 'Stack2']";
String[] splitted = text.split("\\['|', *'|'\\]");
```

**Edit:** I just see, that the first entry in the array would be an empty String. So maybe better go with the solution in one of the comments:

```
String[] splitted2 = text.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|'", "").split(", *");
```

BTW, this allows separating the elements by comma + space or just comma without space.

Comment: in my console :
original:["Scenario 1","Scenario 2"]
changed:["Scenario 1", "Scenario 2"]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could split on the " which would give you an array with the contents: `[`, `Scenario 1`, `,`, `Scenario 2`, `]`.

Then it's just the case of taking every value with an odd index to find the final array which is just a simple mathematical calculation. I would imagine this to be fairly efficient as it involves less string manipulation but I don't know if the overhead of doing more splits would be worth it.